# Sonar, put use private on setters POJOs to avoid duplication

Tags: java, oop, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, object-oriented-analysis

On Rest project I have 3 POJOs class categories, one to persist, other to transfer data from front-end to persist other to transfer data to front-end to show. The POJOs used to transfer data into front-end is common duplicate with the POJOs used to persist they that its because they are a part of these objects, I dont want use some POJO to persist and transfer data into requests I need only part of them and not all data. The Sonar always accused duplication, the solution of my partners is set some seters methods to private to avoid duplication this sounds strange to me, this is a valid solution?
Have any other solution to avoid sonar duplication?

Comment: Can you show problematic code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Sonar documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues), you can specify this under **Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope > Issues**. You would have to specify your classes and this particular issue (duplicated code).